# Set Title for JsonObject

Tags: php, mysql, json

This is too basic , but i tried to google but it's hard to explain what the keyword i neef to search .

Here is my Json

```
{
people: [
{
id: "1",
fname: "sadas",
lname: "asdad",
age: "12"
},
{
id: "2",
fname: "dfdfdf",
lname: "dfdfdf",
age: "334"
},
{
id: "3",
fname: "sdf",
lname: "sdf",
age: "343"
},
{
id: "4",
fname: "dsfsdf",
lname: "sdfsd",
age: "4"
}
],
success: 1
}
```

And i need that before each json object will have something like a title . Like this

```
{
people: [
person: {
id: "1",
fname: "sadas",
lname: "asdad",
age: "12"
},
person:{
id: "2",
fname: "dfdfdf",
lname: "dfdfdf",
age: "334"
},
person:{
id: "3",
fname: "sdf",
lname: "sdf",
age: "343"    
},
person:{
id: "4",
fname: "dsfsdf",
lname: "sdfsd",
age: "4"
}
],
success: 1
}
```

And here is my php code

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
 $people= array();

$people["id"] = $row["id"];
$people["fname"] = $row["fname"];
$people["lname"] = $row["lname"];
$people["age"] = $row["age"];

array_push($response["people"] , $people);
}


$response["success"] = 1;

echo json_encode($response);
```

Please help me
Any help will be very appreciated !!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $person = array();   
    $person["id"] = $row["id"];
    $person["fname"] = $row["fname"];
    $person["lname"] = $row["lname"];
    $person["age"] = $row["age"];
    array_push($response["people"] , array('person'=>$person));
}
$response["success"] = 1;
echo json_encode($response);
```

Comment: Thanks for answer but
I got this error   :
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=>' (T_DOUBLE_ARROW) in C:\wamp\www\people\get_all_people.php on line 38

Comment: there is a typo in `array('person'=>$person)`

Comment: What do you means  , Chetak ?

Comment: instead of `array_push($response["people"] , array('person'=>$person));` you can use `$response["people"]= array('person'=>$person);`

Comment: If use $response["people"]= array('person'=>$person); it just have the 4th object , not all array


{
people: {
person: {
id: "4",
fname: "dsfsdf",
lname: "sdfsd",
age: "4"
}
},
success: 1
}